# How do i request an edit to an answer?

Tags: support, editing

Ive asked a question which so far has only received one answer. This answer was good enough to help me figure out the solution for myself, but isnt entirely accurate. I'd like to accept this answer but only after its been edited to show the steps that i took, which ive left in a comment. I don't have enough rep to do the edit myself.

So how do i get the attention of people with enough rep to edit this answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can suggest edits yourself if you don't have the 2000 reputation needed for full edit privileges. Just click on the edit button on the answer and edit away. Your edit has to be approved by a high-reputation user, so it might take a short while until it is visible for everyone.

Comment: Does some sort of alert go out? Or does a high-repper have to be in the question to see my suggested edit?

Comment: @Detnuomnu Users with more than 10k will see a notification about pending edits in the top bar.

Comment: Now i'm waiting for you to edit your answer to reflect our comments. ;)

Comment: @detnuomnu Check this out: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work

Comment: @Jorge Castro Everything i wanted to know, thanks.